# Polynomial term for random walk large deviations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk, large-deviation-theory

Let $S_n = \sum_1^n X_i$ with $P(X_i =1) = p>1/2$ and $P(X_i = -1) = 1-p$ be a biased random walk. Large deviations tell us that $p_0=P(S_n \leq 0) \leq n^a(2 \sqrt{p(1-p)})^n$. We are curious what the exponent $a$ is.

Ignoring parity problems, one can obtain the lower bound
$$p_0 \geq P(S_n = 0) = \binom{n}{n/2} p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2} \approx n^{-1/2} (2 \sqrt{p(1-p)})^n.$$
However, when we take the sum $p_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{-n} P(S_n = k)$, this might increase the $-1/2$ exponent. Since $\sum_1^{n} k^{-1/2} \approx n^{1/2}$, I am inclined to guess that $p_0 \approx n^{1/2} (2 \sqrt{p(1-p)})^n$. However, there also seems to be some additional penalty for going far behind $0$, so maybe $-1/2$ is sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer.

---

**A heuristic computation.** Let $D(x||p) = x \log\left(\frac{x}{p}\right) + (1-x)\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1-p}\right)$ denote the Kullback-Leibler divergence of $\operatorname{Ber}(x)$ w.r.t. $\operatorname{Ber}(p)$ and write $r = 2\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ for simplicity. Then

$$ \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{r^n} \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \approx \frac{1}{\left(\frac{k}{n}\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \right)^{1/2}} e^{-n \left( D(\frac{k}{n}||p) - D(\frac{1}{2}||p) \right)} $$

tells that we can expect

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[S_n \leq 0]
&\approx \frac{r^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} \frac{1}{\left( \frac{k}{n}\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \right)^{1/2}} e^{-n \left( D(\frac{k}{n}||p) - D(\frac{1}{2}||p) \right)} \\
&\approx \frac{r^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \sum_{j\in\{\frac{n}{2}-k:1\leq k\leq\frac{n}{2}\}} 2e^{jD'(\frac{1}{2}||p)}, \qquad (j = \tfrac{n}{2}-k) \\
&\approx \frac{r^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \cdot\frac{2p}{2p-1} \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}(n \text{ mod } 2)}.
\end{align*}

This matches numerical computations as well, and I believe that this can be justified with some efforts. (Obtaining the correct order only up to constants would be easier.) I will update my answer if I come up with a rigorous justification.

---

**A more rigorous computation.** We have the following result:

> **Claim.** For each $p \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ and $n\geq 1$, let $N_n$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$. Then there exist constants $0 < c_1 < c_2$, depending only on $p$, such that
>
> $$ \forall n \geq 1 \ : \quad c_1 \frac{r^n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mathbf{P}[N_n \leq n/2] \leq c_2 \frac{r^n}{\sqrt{n}} $$
>
> with $r = 2\sqrt{p(1-p)}$.

*Proof.* By the quantitative version of the Stirling's approximation, $n! = \Theta( n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n} )$ for $n \geq 1$, where $\Theta$ is the [*Big-Theta notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations). Thus for $1 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{2}$,

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
&= \Theta \Bigg( \sqrt{\frac{n}{k(n-k)}} \cdot \frac{n^n}{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \Bigg) \\
&= \Theta \Bigg( \sqrt{\frac{n}{k(n-k)}} e^{-nD(\frac{k}{n}||p)} \Bigg),
\end{align*}

where $D(x||p) := x \log\left(\frac{x}{p}\right) + (1-x)\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1-p}\right)$. Plugging this to the summation describing $\mathbf{P}[N_n \leq n/2]$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[N_n \leq n/2]
&= (1-p)^n + \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \\
&= (1-p)^n + \Theta \Bigg( \frac{r^n}{\sqrt{n}} \underbrace{ \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{k}{n}\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \right)^{1/2}} e^{n \left( D(\frac{1}{2}||p) - D(\frac{k}{n}||p) \right)} }_{=(*)} \Bigg)
\end{align*}

In the last line, we utilized the identity $r = e^{-D(\frac{1}{2}||p)}$. Let $I_n = \{ \frac{n}{2}-k : 1 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{2} \}$ and rewrite the above sum $(*)$ as

\begin{align*}
(*)
&= \sum_{j \in I_n} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{j^2}{n^2} \right)^{1/2}} e^{n \left( D(\frac{1}{2}||p) - D(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{j}{n}||p) \right)}
\end{align*}

Now notice that $x \mapsto D(x||p)$ is convex and strictly decreasing on $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$. From this, it follows that

$$ n \left( D(\tfrac{1}{2}||p) - D(\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{j}{n}||p) \right)
\leq j \frac{\partial D}{\partial x}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}||p\right)
= j \log\left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right). $$

Since $0 < \frac{1-p}{p} < 1$, Using this, we can prove that $ (*) = \Theta\left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^j \right) = \Theta(1) $ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

I thought some more and got something similar as Sangchul. A simpler argument goes by making the bound
$$P(S_n = -k) \leq P(S_n=0) \left(\frac{p}{1-p} \right)^{k/2},$$
and summing gives $$P( S_n \leq 0) \leq P(S_n=0) \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{p}{1-p} \right)^{k/2} \leq \frac{C}{1- 2p} n^{-1/2} (2 \sqrt{p(1-p)})^n ,$$
for some $C$ that does not depend on $p$ or $n$.

To show the displayed line observe that 
$$P(S_n = 0) = \binom{n}{n/2} p^{n/2} (1-p)^{n/2} \approx c n^{-1/2} (2 \sqrt{p(1-p)})^n.$$
Using the bound $\binom{n}j \leq \binom n {n/2}$ for all $ 0 \leq j \leq n$ we can write
$$P(S_n = -k) = \binom{n}{(n+k)/2} p^{(n+k)/2} (1-p)^{(n-k)/2}\leq \binom{n}{n/2} p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{k/2}.$$
This is the claimed inequality at the beginning of the note.